# How do I prevent users from going 'back' but retain the cache after a logout in JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, caching, logout, aem

I need to leave cache enabled and disable the user from seeing the information once they go back after logging out.

I'm aware that cached pages showing upon logout + back button is by design within browsers.  I'm aware that disabling cache is a way to force logout + back to force a revalidation.

With JSP (CQ5 specifically), is this even possible?

I have the following solutions in mind, but am not sure which is the best approach for my needs:

1. Disable cache everywhere.  This works, but is unacceptable because the publisher we are using will be too busy re-upping pages.
2. "Logout" button POSTs to Page A.  Page A kills the session and forwards the user to Page B with some "You have been logged out" message.  "Back" from Page B will pop the message browsers provide about having to re-post values.  Yes = they log back out (harmless at this point) and get forwarded to Page B again.  No = they sit at Page A harmlessly.  But, "back" + "no" + "back" may land them on the cached page, or a selection from history would still show a cached page.
3. "Logout" button pops a new window, asking if they're sure/warning them to close their session.  "I'm sure" does a window.opener.reload() or window.opener.close().  But, if JavaScript is disabled, we're doomed.
4. "Logout" posts to the current page.  All pages check the existence of some POSTd value.  If present, forward to Page B with a "you have been logged out message".  Similar to #2.  This will essentially re-cache the page into a "You have been logged out" page, but "Back back" or history will still have cached pages.

Is there some way to manually clear a user's cache, or force the validation check to happen even on cached pages?  I'm out of ideas here...

Comment: Only about 2% of users disable JavaScript. Do any of your users do so?

Comment: We could assume that everybody has JS on and just degrade gracefully, perhaps a message saying "close your browser", but if we're going that approach then one of the others + a message saying to close your browser seems better anyway.

Comment: how do you want disable cache? you mean disable it within browser?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is that you are trying to cache something that should be kept secret. Caching information behind a password is not secure and is a risk.

However, it may make sense to cache the generic html parts of a page behind a password. Anything that any logged in user can see is OK in this regard. It is only the specific information such as username, address, phone number etc that is sensitive.

If you make a separate JSON call to pull down the data, the infomration will be lightweight, but still secure, as it is not cached on the system, but also not padded with html formatting etc.

The page can also have the intelligence to display a log in challenge if the users session has been interrupted for whatever reason, they retype and continue from where they left off, whilst still keeping the back button in place.

I would also think if there is any sensitive information is kept in the history, such as id's, actions etc, that can be a problem as well.

Just a few things to consider.